# How to have non-const access to object held by a container when the container is const in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, const-correctness

I have a relationship between two classes and some additional functional code illustrated in the below example.  The `MiddleMan` class holds a couple of containers of pointers to `DataObject` class instances.  I want to enforce read-only access to the data objects in one container, while allowing write access to the data containers in the other.  Users of `MiddleMan` should never be able to modify the containers themselves directly (the `ptr_vector` members).

I guess there is const promotion happening to the `DataObject` pointers when accessed through the `MiddleMan` const member function.  How can I avoid this?   In my object relationship, `MiddleMan` does not logically own the `DataObject` instances.  Thus, I do not want the `DataObject` instances const-protected.

I have used the `boost::ptr_vector` container as I understand the STL containers can be more problematic for this sort of thing.  Didn't solve my problem though.
I am happy to use const_cast in `MiddleMan`, but I don't see how to.

```
// const correctness access through middleman example
// g++ -I/Developer/boost  ptr_container_ex.cc
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

struct DataObject
{
    DataObject(size_t n) : _data(new float[n]) {}
    ~DataObject() {delete _data;}
    float * dataNonConst() { return _data; }
    const float * dataConst() const { return _data; }
    float * _data;
};


struct MiddleMan
{

    typedef boost::ptr_vector<DataObject> containerVec_t;

    const containerVec_t & inputVars() const { return _inputVars; }
    const containerVec_t & outputVars() const { return _outputVars; }

    void addInputVar(  DataObject * in  ) { _inputVars.push_back( in ); }
    void addOutputVar( DataObject * out ) { _outputVars.push_back( out ); }

    containerVec_t _inputVars, _outputVars;

};

// just an example that the DataObject instances are managed externally
DataObject g_dataInstances[] = {DataObject(1), DataObject(2), DataObject(3)};

MiddleMan theMiddleMan;


int main()
{
    theMiddleMan.addInputVar( &g_dataInstances[0]);  // this is just setup
    theMiddleMan.addOutputVar( &g_dataInstances[1]);

    const MiddleMan & mmRef = theMiddleMan; // I actually only have a const ref to work with

    // read data example
    const MiddleMan::containerVec_t & inputs = mmRef.inputVars();
    float read = inputs[0].dataConst()[0];

    // write data example
    const MiddleMan::containerVec_t & outputs = mmRef.outputVars();
    float * data_ptr = outputs[0].dataNonConst(); // COMPILER ERROR HERE:

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the compiler output:

```
ptr_container_ex.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
ptr_container_ex.cc:49: error: passing ‘const DataContainer’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘float* DataContainer::dataNonConst()’ discards qualifiers
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One working scenario uses `const_cast` in accessing the outputVars.  I'm not able to return a reference to the whole container, but I can get the functionality I need returning begin and end iterators.

```
// const correctness access through middleman example
// g++ -I/Developer/boost  ptr_container_ex.cc
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

struct DataObject
{
    DataObject(size_t n) : _data(new float[n]) {}
    ~DataObject() {delete _data;}
    float * dataNonConst() { return _data; }
    const float * dataConst() const { return _data; }
    float * _data;
};


struct MiddleMan
{
    typedef boost::ptr_vector<DataObject> containerVec_t;

    containerVec_t::iterator outputVarsBegin() const { return const_cast<containerVec_t&>(_outputVars).begin(); }
    containerVec_t::iterator outputVarsEnd() const { return const_cast<containerVec_t&>(_outputVars).end(); }

    const containerVec_t & inputVars() const { return _inputVars; }

    void addInputVar(  DataObject * in  ) { _inputVars.push_back( in ); }
    void addOutputVar( DataObject * out ) { _outputVars.push_back( out ); }

    containerVec_t _inputVars, _outputVars;

};

// just an example that the DataObject instances are managed externally
DataObject g_dataInstances[] = {DataObject(1), DataObject(2), DataObject(3)};

MiddleMan theMiddleMan;


int main()
{
    theMiddleMan.addInputVar( &g_dataInstances[0]);  // this is just setup
    theMiddleMan.addOutputVar( &g_dataInstances[1]);

    const MiddleMan & mmRef = theMiddleMan; // I actually only have a const ref to work with

    // read data example
    const MiddleMan::containerVec_t & inputs = mmRef.inputVars();
    float read = inputs[0].dataConst()[0];

    // write data example
    float * data_ptr2 = mmRef.outputVarsBegin()->dataNonConst(); // WORKS

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude const modifiers every place you are not going to have const access:

```
containerVec_t & outputVars() { return _outputVars; } //Change definition in MiddleMan class

MiddleMan::containerVec_t & outputs = theMiddleMan.outputVars(); //Change reference type
float * data_ptr = outputs[0].dataNonConst(); //No compiler error here
```

Comment: With that approach, users of MiddleMan are able to modify the outputVars container.
`outputs.push_back(&g_dataInstances[0]);`
This is contrary to intent of the interface.